# Как сделать QGraphicsItem, который может быть и картинкой, и текстом?

Tags: c++, qt

Хочу сделать графический элемент, который может быть или картинкой, или текстом. То есть, у этого у элемента есть настройка "Отображать как картинку" и я хочу, чтобы в зависимости от этого выводилась либо картинка, либо текст.

Сейчас мой граф. элемент отнаследован от `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, но я так и не нашел способа сделать так, чтобы я мог писать в него текст.

Как мне совместить возможность отображения и текста, и картинки? Не наследовать же от `QGraphicsPixmapItem` и от `QGraphicsTextItem`?

Или может нужно отнаследовать свой `QGraphicsItem`, в котором я должен буду это все реализовать? Тогда подскажите, примерный порядок действий потому, что в гугле ничего подобного найти я не смог.

Comment: вам надо переопределять функцию `paintEvent()` и там уже определять конкретное поведение вашего итема в зависимости от настроек. Например при опции "я-картинка" вызывать QGraphicsPixmapItem::paintEvent(), при опции "я-текст" рисовать текс самому с помощью QPainter или другими средствами

Comment: кстати, чисто теоретически можете попробовать пронаследоваться от QGraphicsPixmapItem и QGraphicsTextItem и в paintEvent вызывать ивент нужного родителя в зависимости от настройки, возможно сработает

Comment: goldstar_labs, пробовал наследоваться от обоих классов, но этот способ мне не подошел, потому что в другом месте кода вызывались функции, которые были у обоих классов, соответственно, происходил неоднозначный вызов перегруженной функции.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, проблема решилась тем, что я отнаследовал элемент от QGraphicsItem и переопределил метод QGraphicsItem::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget) в своем классе.

В нем, если режим отображения "картинка", то вызывается метод paint->drawPixmap(...), а если "текст", то paint->drawText(...).

Спасибо, goldstar_labs